# 'document.Form1.imgLoading' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp-classic, controls

Could someone help please, i'm stuck on the following error:

> 'document.Form1.imgLoading' is null or not an object  control.js, line 55 character 2

Which is:

Line 55: `document.Form1.imgLoading.style.width=370`

From:

```
function setLoading(){
    var strPath = "../images/"
    var strFName = "searchingText.gif"
    var strSearchPath = ""

    //15/2if (!document.Form1.TextBoxLangID.value == "") { //SO LANG USED
    //  strSearchPath = strPath + document.Form1.TextBoxLangID.value + "/brand/" + strFName
    //}
    //else{
    //  strSearchPath = strPath +  "brand/" + strFName
    //15/2}

    //document.Form1.imgSearchingText.src = strSearchPath
    document.Form1.imgLoading.style.width=370
    document.Form1.imgLoading.style.height=328
    document.Form1.imgLoading.style.left = 327
    document.Form1.imgLoading.style.top = 220
    document.Form1.imgLoading.style.zIndex=2000'
```

Comment: Heres the javascript in the index.aspx

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['Form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.Form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>

Comment: It is saying that you have no element with the name "imgLoading".

Comment: Why would this only be a problem when running it on a virtual machine it also runs on other virtual machines with no errors. Is this an IIS problem?

Comment: It is impossible to tell you why with what you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are referring like `form.controlname`. In ASP.Net the control names are generated like ctl$imgLoading etc based on Master page/nested control configuration.

> Better avoid `document.Form1.imgLoading` and make use of referring it
>   based on id using native `document.getElementById()`

If you have the script code in `.aspx` page, Please use the below code to refer the element

```
var imgLoading=document.getElementById('<%= imgLoading.ClientID %>');
imgLoading.style.width=370;
```

In case if you have the `script in JS file`
Make sure you set the `ClientIDMode=static`<kbd>Supported from ASP.Net 4.0 only</kbd> for imgLoading control in .aspx page, then

```
var imgLoading=document.getElementById('imgLoading');
imgLoading.style.width=370;
```

Comment: Thank you Murail, I will remember this!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, but I just want to say that if your `<script>` tags are in the `<head>` section, place your script tags at the back of the body section, or load the script `onload` of the document.

This is because the image that is in the `<body>` section of your document has yet to be loaded, so it is `null or not an object`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If imgLoading is a asp:Image control then you have to find it using next code:

```
document.getElementById('<%= imgLoading.ClientID %>').style.width = 370
```

Comment: I just tried this and it gave me 'Object doesn't support this property or method'